# A variable is not being passed from the previous function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Doing an assignment and can't get a variable passed between two methods in the same class.

```
global check
wage = 0
hours = 0
check = 0


class employee:
  def __init__(self, name, wage, hours, check):
    self.name = name
    self.wage = wage
    self.hours = hours
    self.check = check

  def paycheck(self):
    if self.hours > 41:
      self.hours = self.hours - 40
      overtime = self.wage * self.hours * 1.5
      self.check = (40 * self.wage) + overtime
      return self.check
      #print(self.check)
    else:
      self.check = self.hours * self.wage
      return self.check
      #print(self.check)
    
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name + ":\n Net Pay: $" + str(self.check)



A_emp = employee("Alice", 20, 40, 0)
B_emp = employee("Bob", 15, 50, 0)

print(A_emp)
print(B_emp)
```

The output should display the 'Net Pay' of each employee, and works to display most of the **str** method:

```
Alice:
 Net Pay: $0
Bob:
 Net Pay: $0
```

However, the *check* variable just wont pass values between class methods. I've globalized it, defined it outside of the class, and tried different variations of *self.check* vs *check*. Feel like I'm just throwing things and nothing is sticking. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where do you actually call `paycheck()`? If you try `A_emp.paycheck()` you will see the check change, because that function actually does the work.

Comment: You instantiated the `employee` class but you never call the `paycheck()` method on it anywhere

Comment: Why did you define `global check` ? it's already a global variable and I think you intended to pass them as argument to your class's initializer

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the paycheck() method.  Also get rid of your global variables and return statements.

```
class employee:
    def __init__(self, name, wage, hours, check):
        self.name = name
        self.wage = wage
        self.hours = hours
        self.check = check

    def paycheck(self):
        if self.hours > 41:
            self.hours = self.hours - 40
            overtime = self.wage * self.hours * 1.5
            self.check = (40 * self.wage) + overtime

        else:
            self.check = self.hours * self.wage

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ":\n Net Pay: $" + str(self.check)


A_emp = employee("Alice", 20, 40, 0)
B_emp = employee("Bob", 15, 50, 0)

A_emp.paycheck()
B_emp.paycheck()

print(A_emp)
print(B_emp)
```

Output:

```
Alice:
 Net Pay: $800
Bob:
 Net Pay: $825.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So I basically defined the methods, but just by running the class I wasn't necessarily storing the values to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the class object you need to call

A_emp.paycheck()

B_emp.paycheck()